# Get all Activities to one Account - CRM 2016

Tags: sql, t-sql, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

my question is, is it possible to get all Activities for one Account in CRM by a SQL-Query in a acceptable period of time?

Surprising is, that all the Activities are in the Account-Overview in CRM. And that page loads instantly.

I've build a query just for Email-Activities. The query runs round about 25mins. Which is not suprising to me xD. But i can't find a clear relationship between the 2 tables.

Some data:
~460000 Email-Activities
~28000 Contacts
~37000 Accounts

Here's the sql-query:

```
    select account.Name, Max(email.CreatedOn) from Email     
    as email
    join Contact as contact on email.DirectionCode = 1
    and datediff(wk, email.CreatedOn, GetDate()) > 12  
    and (email.ToRecipients Like '%' + contact.EMailAddress1 +'%'
    or email.ToRecipients Like '%' + contact.EMailAddress2 +'%'
    or email.ToRecipients Like '%' + contact.EMailAddress3 +'%') 
    join Account as account on account.AccountId = contact.AccountId
    Group by account.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your qry. When you use like with '%...' it will newer use index.

The best solution in your case is catch qry (with SQL Server Profiler (in SSSMS -> tools -> SQL profiler)) - It'll give you information about dataset and you can get connection between tables via reverse analysis.

Comment: Hi, jea the problem with the index was known to me but that was the only solution at that time. I've done it with the sql profiler. But atm i dont get it what for ID's he's using. I'll try hard and let you guys know if i got an solution.